# Programmatically change drawable and shape color in layer list?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a layer list like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_pin"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</layer-list>
```

How can I programmatically change the color of the shape as well as the drawable?

For example, how can I change the color to `#FF0000` and change the drawable to `@drawable/ic_globe` programmatically?

Answer (score 6):

Please Add `id` attribute to item of layer like below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bg_layer">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/top_layer"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_pin"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</layer-list>
```

**Code in Java**

```
LayerDrawable bgDrawable = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border);/*drawable*/
GradientDrawable bg_layer = (GradientDrawable)bgDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId (R.id.bg_layer);/*findDrawableByLayerId*/
bg_layer.setColor(Color.RED);/*set color to layer*/
bgDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.top_layer,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_globe));/*set drawable to layer*/
image.setImageDrawable(bgDrawable);/*set drawable to image*/
```

*Here* `R.drawable.border` is my drawable, `R.id.bg_layer` and `top_layer` are ids of items of layerlist in drawable

I hope its work for you